# Cannot put main content in the center

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, alignment

i've making a layout using `flexbox` of a how a typical website looks like ,but i've got a few questions and a couple problems . My first question is that how can i improve this layout? and the problem I'm having is that i cant put the `main__content` in color `black` in between `aside`..

```css
*{

    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    color: black;
    font-size: 40px;
}

body{
        background: lightslategray;
}

.header{

    display: flex;
}

.zero{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 200px;
    background: violet;
    
}

.one{

    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: blue;
    flex-grow: 2;}

.two{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: red;
    flex-grow: 2;

}

.aside {
    display: flex;
 
}

.three{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: green;

}

.four{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 200px;
    background: yellow;
    margin-left: auto;
    

}

.main .content{

    height: 50vh;
    width: 40vh;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<body>

    <div class="header">
        <div class="one">content</div>
        <div class="two">content</div>
        <div class="three">content</div>

    </div>
    <div class="aside">
        <div class="zero">sidebar</div>
        <div class="four">sidebar</div>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
        <div class="content">Main__content</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can we change the HTML?

Comment: yeah,whatever you want to change

Comment: Try to put sidebar inside the main `div` class

Answer (score 0):

Here your are trying to apply styles to both the main and content

```
.main .content{
    
        height: 50vh;
        width: 40vh;
        background-color: black;
    }
```

so the child div (content) has height and width same as its parent div(main)

Try to apply:

```
.main {

        height: 50vh;
        width: 40vh;
        background-color: black;
        }


.content {
    color: brown;
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```